# when for each loop is executed it is showing o/pSystem.Int32[].What is the correct syntax to display using foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArray = new int[3];
            int i;
            for (i= 0;i< 3;i++)
            {

                myArray[i]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            foreach (int j in myArray)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("o/p" +myArray);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem and what you tried in order to fix it. Don't just paste code on us

Comment: either do `Console.WriteLine("o/p" +j);` or get rid of the loop and use `String.join`.

Comment: @Aominè Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot you already got the values:

```
Console.WriteLine("o/p" + j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      foreach (int j in myArray){
            Console.WriteLine("o/p " + j);
        }
```

Comment: It would be a much better answer if you explained what the code does.